# Tabs in Bootstraps?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have created my tab like this->

```
                   <li id="tab-1" class="">
                        <a href="#tab-content-1" data-toggle="tab">
                              <div class="tab-menu-content">
                                <div class="cm">Travel, Leisure & Hospitality</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="tab-2" class="">
                        <a href="#tab-content-2" data-toggle="tab">
                            <div class="tab-menu-content">
                                <div class="cm">Media, Publishing & Entertainment</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

and there contents like this ->

```
       <div id="tab-content-1" class="tab-pane-active ">
                    <div class="fade in">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="content-holder">
                                        <ul class="li-no-bottom">
                                            <li>Travel listings</li>
                                            <li>User reviews</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-content-2" class="tab-pane ">
                <div class="fade in">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                                <div class="content-holder">
                                    <ul class="li-no-bottom">
                                        <li>Questions and answers</li>
                                        <li>Mobile apps &amp; games</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But whenever I am clicking on the table, its corresponding content is not switching. Only the active content is being displayed.

Comment: that's not looking proper bootstrap tab structure find info here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: show us how you get the correspond content :)